# How to create a Spinner widget inside of a PopupWindow in Android? Get BadTokenException when clicking on Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, popupwindow

I've been searching the web for the solution to this problem, but, unfortunately, I can't seem to find the answer.  I created an XML file for a PopupWindow with a Spinner inside of it.  Inside a button event listener, I call the following code to inflate the PopupWindow and display it on the screen.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
settings_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_popout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.setting_popout));

// Creates a popup window of required width and height, and displays
// the popup in the center of the screen.
pw_settings = new PopupWindow(settings_layout, 400, 470, true); 
pw_settings.showAtLocation(settings_layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

spColors = (Spinner) settings_layout.findViewById(R.id.linecolor);

// Sets the initial values of the color spinner and the listener
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_color = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.colors_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_color.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spColors.setAdapter(adapter_color);
spColors.setSelection(adapter_color.getPosition(over.color));
```

When clicking the button, the popup window shows up fine.  However, I get the following error in LogCat when I click on the Spinner.

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41402a90 is not valid; is your activity running?
>   ...

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, why not use ListPopupWindow: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be a bit late, and not exactly an answer to the original question, but I found from another question here that inserting the following line into the xml for my spinner prevented that error from occurring.

`android:spinnerMode="dialog"`

Comment: This is not working at api level Android 25.

Answer (score 1):

I have run in to this problem a couple of times now, and the only non time consuming method I have found is the one proposed by Mike Fosker above.

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

makes the options list for the spinner show up in a separate pop-up, which does not trip the initial pop-up window you opened in your code. 
For example :

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/myspinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Comment: Can you add example of configuration or code here?, the links could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
settings_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_popout, null);
((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.setting_popout)).addView(settings_layout);
```

Also, why are you attaching the layout in your popup to a `ViewGroup` already inside your activity? Chances are you can just get away with:

```
settings_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_popout, null);
```

Comment: True, I didn't need the (ViewGroup) part above (the popup still shows without that part).  But, unfortunately, the same problem still occurs, BadTokenException when the Spinner is clicked. Thanks though!

Comment: When the Popup shows up, do you `finish()` the Activity by chance? Can you post your onClick for the button to cause the Popup to show?

Comment: No I did not, unfortunately.  But sure, I will post the rest of the onClick in the original question.  I only posted the code that I thought was pertinent right now.

Comment: Consider my other comment too, using a ListPopUpWindow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420609/how-to-create-a-spinner-widget-inside-of-a-popupwindow-in-android-get-badtokene/11420741#comment15064630_11420609

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Although I didn't figure out how to use the ListPopupWindow, your comment led me to use dialogs (without titles) instead of an ordinary PopupWindow. Using dialogs solved the problem!