# Error spinner in popup window when I click

Tags: android, click, spinner, popupwindow

My app if poulsas a button a pop-out which has two spinners, well then I get the pop-up there all right but when I get the error is when I click on the spinner.

Here you have my below code and debug, because logcat I get everything right.

```
 public void añadirRegistro(View v){

         showPopup(leer_registros.this);
    }
    private void showPopup(final Activity context) {

           Spinner eleccionIP,eleccionRegistro;
           borrar_datos BorrarDatos = new borrar_datos ();
           // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
           RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
           LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);


           eleccionIP = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupIP);
           eleccionRegistro = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupRegistro);



           /*Cursor cur=BorrarDatos.obtenerIP();
           BorrarDatos.rellenarSpinner(cur,eleccionIP);*/


           final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
           popup.setContentView(layout);
           popup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           popup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           popup.setFocusable(true);

           popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 200, 200);


           ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

           adapter.add("item 1");
           adapter.add("item 2");
           eleccionIP.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
```

Debug:

```
WindowManagerGlobal.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams, Display, Window) line: 255    
WindowManagerImpl.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams) line: 69    
PopupWindow.invokePopup(WindowManager$LayoutParams) line: 993   
PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(View, int, int) line: 899    
Spinner$DropdownPopup(ListPopupWindow).show() line: 603 
Spinner$DropdownPopup.show() line: 981  
Spinner.performClick() line: 609    
View$PerformClick.run() line: 17355 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

The debug of my second mistake:

```
Scada [Android Application] 
    DalvikVM[localhost:8636]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException))   
            WindowManagerGlobal.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams, Display, Window) line: 255    
            WindowManagerImpl.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams) line: 69    
            PopupWindow.invokePopup(WindowManager$LayoutParams) line: 993   
            PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(View, int, int) line: 899    
            Spinner$DropdownPopup(ListPopupWindow).show() line: 603 
            Spinner$DropdownPopup.show() line: 981  
            Spinner.performClick() line: 609    
            View$PerformClick.run() line: 17355 
            Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
            ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
            Looper.loop() line: 137 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
        Thread [<11> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
        Thread [<12> AsyncTask #2] (Running)    
        Thread [<13> AsyncTask #3] (Running)    
        Thread [<14> AsyncTask #4] (Running)    
        Thread [<15> AsyncTask #5] (Running)
```

I did debug, and error must be here:

```
RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.popup);
           LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);


           eleccionIP = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupIP);
           eleccionRegistro = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupRegistro);
```

Comment: is this a complete log that you have posted ?

Comment: yes!, please help! nobody helps me...

Comment: how about debugging it and finding what line exactly is causing the problem ?

Comment: is not that line is exactly the problem, I just do that every time I take a click the program stops and goes directly to ADT and I get the debug, which is what I have set up.

Comment: could you change the constructor to Context instead of activity and the using that to instantiate the popup ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand very well, I could give an example? is that I am new to android programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change this showPopup(final Activity context) to showPopup(final Context context)

Comment: I keep getting the same error doing as you say ...

Comment: could u comment the adapter.setdropdown resource method and check temporarily if thats the one causing the issue ? and try passing context to the arrayadapter constructor instead of this

Comment: the second part of your response context not understand exactly what you want to do. The first part I have, what to put in comments. SetDropDownViewResource and gives me the same error = (= (

Comment: a simple thing to debug this then is to comment every line from the back. that is start leave the popup initialization line and comment the rest. run the app. kip doing this, until you know whats wrong and where

Comment: are you writing all of these in the same activity ? or different ?

Comment: change this line RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.popup);  to RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.popup);

Comment: I keep getting the same error doing as you say ...  oh my good.... this is frustating =(

Comment: Don't give up as a developer. keep debugging while i look at it :)

Comment: do you need the viewGroup layout ?

Comment: thank you very much indeed, I am eternally grateful for all this help ... =) =)

Comment: they actually do not know ... I know that I use for this: View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);

Comment: ur issue is resolved ?

Comment: i dont understand you... sorry...

Comment: have you solved the error ?

Comment: I have not tried it to view group, because if I comment that part of the code gives me this error: View layout = layoutInflater.inflate (R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, ViewGroup);

Comment: try replacing viewGroup to null .. View layout = layoutInflater.inflate (R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, null);

Comment: nothing.... the same error....

Answer (score 20):

Adding **android:spinnerMode="dialog"** in spinner solved my problem.

[How to create a Spinner widget inside of a PopupWindow in Android? Get BadTokenException when clicking on Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420609/how-to-create-a-spinner-widget-inside-of-a-popupwindow-in-android-get-badtokene/22310732#22310732)

Comment: Thanks a lot,save my time. :)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this same problem.Add your spinner in xml class.

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the appropriate lines with this and see what happens:

```
final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, new ViewGroup(this) {

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

    eleccionIP = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupIP);
    eleccionRegistro = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupRegistro);



    /*Cursor cur=BorrarDatos.obtenerIP();
    BorrarDatos.rellenarSpinner(cur,eleccionIP);*/



    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setFocusable(true);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 200, 200);
        }

    }, 100L);

    ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    adapter.add("item 1");
    adapter.add("item 2");
    eleccionIP.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top) will help in creating a popupwindow and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153651/set-own-layout-in-popup-window-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top) also

Comment: me da error en viewGroup... error: Multiple markers at this line
 - ViewGroup cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method inflate(int, ViewGroup) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, new 
  ViewGroup(){})

Comment: try cleaning the project.

Comment: Go to project, on the menu bar in eclipse and select clean, select this project. and also make sure the LayoutInflater line in ur code is present with this replacement code

Comment: then i think u will have to search on google and first create a new project that only deals with a pop up window :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set spinner inside popup window then do the following:

```
//this your inside layout
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//and that is your spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterState =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        layoutInflater.getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        keysState);

        adapterState.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerState.setAdapter(adapterState);
```

Use layout.getContext() instead of getApplicationContext() or Activty.this etc
 because your are inside the another layout view.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

//Declaer your array list fist and add some itms

```
  private ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
  item.add("1");
  item.add("2");
```

// Change your array adapter like this

```
  ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  eleccionIP.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: as you put it fails me I have to put it like this: ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
     list.add("1");
     list.add("2");
     ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        eleccionIP.setAdapter(adapter);